# .Find can't find date argument in date column, unless formats match

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

In a userform textbox, user enters date. The following function tests whether the table already has an entry for the date that the user is trying to input:

```
If testProductEntry(CDate(tbDate), cbShift, cbProductNumber) = True Then
```

The function to find the date in the ws is the following:

```
Public Function testProductEntry(ByRef v As Date, w As String, x As String) As Boolean

    Dim f As Range, rng As Range, fA As String
    Set rng = tblProductionData.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
    Set f = rng.Find(v)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        fA = f.Address
        Do
            If f.Offset(0, 1) = w And f.Offset(0, 3) = x Then
                testProductEntry = True
                Exit Do
            Else
                Set f = rng.FindNext(f)
            End If
        Loop While Not f.Address = fA
    Else
        testProductEntry = False
    End If

End Function
```

In the ws, I've changed formats to be date type.

If I let the function pass the first argument as a string, or if I match the foromats between input and what the column format is, the process works fine.

But, isn't that the point of using date data type, so that the value needn't be used as a string AND format types (because dates are integers) are ignored, that is, it looks at the value?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Use data validation on that cell to control what the user enters.

Comment: Maybe more information would clarify the problem.  If I pass a date to your `testProductEntry` function, the `.Find`  works no matter the numberformat of the cell in the column.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, thank you for your comment. That's my problem! If I pass a date type value, the function returns false because it can't find the value in the table (although it exists.) If I instead feed the date as a string, function works fine. The other issue is format. I keep the format as "mm/dd/yy" (08/13/21). I wrap CDate() around the argument of the call function. But when it arrives at the function (which is receives the argument "as Date", the format gets changed to "m/d/yyyy" (8/13/2021)

Comment: As I wrote, I cannot reproduce your problem.  That is why I asked for **more** information, not a repeat of what you've already written. Excel does not really have a **Date datatype**. Dates in Excel are merely numbers (doubles) representing days and fractions of a day (since `1-Jan-1900`, usually). Perhaps if you read the HELP pages for information as to [[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it may help you to **edit** your question to provide sufficient data to allow me to reproduce your problem.